# Collapse SQL rows

Tags: sql, group-by, procedure

Say I have this table:

```
id  |  name  
-------------
1   |  john  
2   |  steve
3   |  steve
4   |  john
5   |  steve
```

I only want the rows that are unique compared to the previous row, these:

```
id  |  name  
-------------
1   |  john  
2   |  steve
4   |  john
5   |  steve
```

I can partly achieve this by using this query:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT `name` FROM demotable WHERE id=t.id-1
) AS prevName FROM demotable AS t GROUP BY prevName ORDER BY id ASC
```

But when I am using a query with multiple UNIONs and stuff, this gets way to complicated. Is there an easy way to do this (like GROUP BY, but than more specific)?

Comment: Which database product are you using? Some of them have features specifically for this sort of task.

Comment: Looks like `MySQL` from the `backticks`? Is your `id` column guaranteed sequential?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you give us some more context, we might be able to suggest an even better way of accomplishing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but I don't know if it's simpler :

```
select demotable.*
from demotable
left join demotable as prev on prev.id = demotable.id - 1
where demotable.name != prev.name
```

Comment: Use a left join, or you miss the first row.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!, I added "OR prev.name IS NULL" so that it also returns the first row.`SELECT demotable.*
FROM demotable
LEFT JOIN demotable AS PREV ON prev.id = demotable.id - 1
WHERE demotable.name != prev.name OR prev.name IS NULL`